# SIGSEGV : Sporadic crash issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, xcode8, crash-reports

Here is my first attempt to solve crash issue in iOS app. Sharing some crash logs here.

```
Exception Type:  SIGSEGV
Exception Codes: SEGV_ACCERR at 0x97ad6beb8
Crashed Thread:  11

Application Specific Information:
objc_msgSend() selector name: length
```

and here is my 11th thread.

```
Thread 11 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x0000000180558150 objc_msgSend + 16
1   Foundation                           0x00000001824f3f60 -[NSString compare:] + 28
2   Foundation                           0x00000001824d88e0 _NSCompareObject + 60
3   CoreFoundation                       0x0000000181a99bd0 __CFSimpleMergeSort + 88
4   CoreFoundation                       0x0000000181a99c60 __CFSimpleMergeSort + 232
5   CoreFoundation                       0x0000000181a99c60 __CFSimpleMergeSort + 232
6   CoreFoundation                       0x0000000181a99c60 __CFSimpleMergeSort + 232
7   CoreFoundation                       0x0000000181a99c60 __CFSimpleMergeSort + 232
8   CoreFoundation                       0x0000000181a99c60 __CFSimpleMergeSort + 232
9   CoreFoundation                       0x0000000181a99c60 __CFSimpleMergeSort + 232
10  CoreFoundation                       0x0000000181a99c60 __CFSimpleMergeSort + 232
11  CoreFoundation                       0x0000000181a99c60 __CFSimpleMergeSort + 232
12  CoreFoundation                       0x0000000181a99c60 __CFSimpleMergeSort + 232
13  CoreFoundation                       0x0000000181a99c60 __CFSimpleMergeSort + 232
14  CoreFoundation                       0x0000000181a99c60 __CFSimpleMergeSort + 232
15  CoreFoundation                       0x00000001819c585c CFSortIndexes + 460
16  CoreFoundation                       0x00000001819c6f9c CFMergeSortArray + 372
17  Foundation                           0x00000001824d80e8 _sortedObjectsUsingDescriptors + 568
18  Foundation                           0x00000001825c64e0 -[NSSet(NSKeyValueSorting) sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:] + 536
19  Eikon                                0x0000000100198b98 __51-[EIKNewsHeadlineStoreManager saveHeadlines:block:]_block_invoke (EIKNewsHeadlineStoreManager.m:67)
20  CoreData                             0x0000000183e5e214 developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 148
21  libdispatch.dylib                    0x000000018099a9a0 _dispatch_client_callout + 12
22  libdispatch.dylib                    0x00000001809a8ad4 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 924
23  libdispatch.dylib                    0x000000018099e2cc _dispatch_queue_invoke + 880
24  libdispatch.dylib                    0x00000001809a8fa8 _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 340
25  libdispatch.dylib                    0x00000001809aaa50 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 536
26  libdispatch.dylib                    0x00000001809aa7d0 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 120
27  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x0000000180ba31d0 _pthread_wqthread + 1092
28  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x0000000180ba2d7c start_wqthread + 0
```

What i am trying to do is get some news headlines from server every 5 or 10 secs, sort them in some order using NSSortDescriptors and then store them in my CoreData. And that is what exactly `saveHeadlines:block` method is doing inside my class.

What exactly `objc_msgSend() selector name: length`
 mean here? Any help is appreciated.

Note: Its a sporadic issue. When i test in simulator or my devices its not crashing. But some users of our app are reporting this crash.

Edited question: inside saveHeadlines:block method

```
        __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    [self.privateMOC performBlock:^{

        NSMutableArray *newsTopics = [[EIKNewsTopicStoreManager managedObjectsInManagedObjectContext:self.privateMOC] mutableCopy];
        [newsTopics addObjectsFromArray:[EIKNewsTopicStoreManager topicsManagedObjectForNewsFeedInContext:self.privateMOC]];
        weakSelf.storedHeadlines = [NSMutableSet set];

        for (NSManagedObject *storedTopic in newsTopics) {
            [weakSelf.storedHeadlines addObjectsFromArray:[[storedTopic valueForKey:EIKFeedTopicRelationshipItems] allObjects]];
        }

        NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:EIKNewsHeadlineAttributeHeadlineId ascending:YES]];
        NSArray *orderedItems = [items sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
        NSArray *orderedHeadlines = [weakSelf.storedHeadlines sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

And the crash is happening on the last line. i.e

```
 NSArray *orderedHeadlines = [weakSelf.storedHeadlines sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Not able to figure out why.!

My NSManagedObjectContext is initialised like this[i.e privateMOC as shown in above code]

```
NSManagedObjectContext *confinementContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
```

Answer (score 0):

Not much info here, but it looks to me that `NSManagedObjectContext` isn't valid on the thread you are performing your operation.
Please make sure that you perform all operations on the context's private queue. You can do this for example by using `performBlock:` or `performBlockAndWait:`.
Also you can't reuse instances of `NSManagedObject` on different threads than the one you fetched them on.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, inside the above mentioned method i am using "performBlock:" to save all the headlines that i have fetched to CoreData.

Comment: Can you show the code fetching them? Are you sure the fetch is in `performBlock` as well?

Comment: Pls look at the edited question. Also see the line where its crashing.

Comment: @ kkodev. SIGSEGV means we are trying to access invalid memory location right?

Comment: pls see my initialisation of my NSManagedObjectContext. As you said i am using a private queue for that.

Comment: Your code looks good, hard to say what went wrong. Try to strongly capture `weakSelf` inside the block to make sure it exists throughout its execution. Perhaps `self` is getting deallocated while `CoreData` does sorting/fetch. Just a guess though.

Comment: Thanks for that. Will look into it.

Comment: I checked on the self. Its not getting deallocated. Can you pls shed some light on Exception Type:  SIGSEGV
Exception Codes: SEGV_ACCERR at 0x97ad6beb8
Application Specific Information:
objc_msgSend() selector name: length

Comment: Can i do something like " __strong typeof(weakSelf) strongSelf = weakSelf;"  right after the block starts to make sure that even though weakSelf sets to nil, i still will have reference to it inside block?