# iOS CRASH issue - SIGSEGV

Tags: ios, core-data, crash, nssortdescriptor

My application crashes while using `NSSortDescriptor` on a  `NSMutableSet` .

Here is the code

```
NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:EIKNewsHeadlineAttributeHeadlineId ascending:YES]];

NSArray *orderedHeadlines = [weakSelf.storedHeadlines sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Here storedHeadlines is the `NSMutableSet` and my sort descriptor key is `EIKNewsHeadlineAttributeHeadlineId` which is a NSString  `@"headlineId”`.

My mutable set contains objects of a certain class type and that class has a property called `headlineId` on which I am trying to sort the mutable set.

I am performing this sorting inside a `performBlock` on a private Queue. 
I checked my `weakSelf` and the `NSMutableSet`. Both are non nil.

What is causing the issue?

Comment: Do you see any crash log?

Comment: @kapsym pls see the crash log here https://stackoverflow.com/q/44453824/1512106

Answer (score 3):

From the crash log it looks like some of the elements in your array are not `NSString`. The line that says this is `objc_msgSend() selector name: length`

This means the objects in the array do not respond to the `length` selector.

I believe the problem is in the JSON to mutable set parsing. If you would print the contents of the set, right before you sort it, it might give you an idea what objects in the array are the wrong ones.

Could you post the code that parses the JSON?

If it is not possible, you could filter the set before sorting, eliminating all elements that are not of type `NSString`

Comment: As you told there is a possibility that some elements in the array may not be of type NSString. My question is how do i assign  a non NSString to an set expecting NSString to reproduce the issue? I am not seeing this crash in my iPhones or iPad but our customers are facing the issue.

Comment: Thanks for a clear explanation. The explanation for  "objc_msgSend() selector name: length " is exactly what i was looking for. Thanks for clearing that out and for the possible work around.